# Divide by characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

so i'm getting help with a problem and this guy tells me to divide a certain matrix A by the characteristic polynomial and get the remainder?

Does this sound right and if so how do you think we can do that?

thank you

Question:
[image: Matrices]

Comment: Please post the actual question so we know what is going on.

Comment: I don't know about your friends hint, but that matrix is diagonizable.

Comment: but how do i divide? is it possible?

Comment: You're not dividing *matrices*, you're dividing polynomials. And yes, it is possible. For example, $x^2+5x+7$ divided by $x+2$ is $x+3$ with remainder $1$. In your case, we want the remainder when, for example, $x^{14}$ is divided by the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: As the other commenter notes, however, it's easier to find this limit by diagonalizing the matrix.